# Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate in ssl mode

Tags: .net, wpf, ssl, iframe

Hi i am deploying wpf XBAP application in iis with ssl certificate. I am accessing above application as
`<iframe src="https://scanner.test.mydomain.com/myscanner Scanner.xbap?Param=@ViewBag.FileName" width="1000" height="600" scrolling="auto"></iframe>`

I am getting popup but i ended up with error Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate.

please find the attached screen shot here

I am struggling to fix this from 2 months. May i get some help to fix this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: ssl over iis is not signing your xbap. in the project property check the trusted box and and add a certificate to sign your xbap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked full trust and also I have created certificate.

Comment: I cannot see the error image you post...so can't help you more - does it works on dev machine with a deploy ?

Comment: It is not in development machine. It is in staging server. I have applied ssl certificate. I have one mvc5 web application and one wpf xaml application. I applied ssl to both. I am trying to access xaml application from web app using iframe as i posted above. It works fine without ssl. It is giving me error in ssl mode. i have posted error message above. Any help or suggestion to fix this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if you click on the red panel in the navigator it must give you the reasons why the certificate is not valid. When IE is displaying the red panel, the error is for the url "https://...." not for the xaml. I am quite sure that if you put a static file in your site you will have the same problem

Comment: Thank you. I have invalid certificate error. So that may be the reason?

Comment: yes, for sure, now you have to find out why...i cannot help more...perhaps find another method to generate it ?